# Google URL Shortener API via java script not working

Tags: javascript, api, google-url-shortener

I use code

```
var api_key = 'Api-key';

function makeRequest() { 
    var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert({'resource': {'longUrl': longurl}});
    request.execute(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(window.got = response));
    });
}

function load() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(api_key);
    gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1', makeRequest);
}
```

and have response

```
{"code":404,"message":"Not Found","data":[{"domain":"global","reason":"notFound","message":"Not Found"}],"error":{"code":404,"message":"Not Found","data":[{"domain":"global","reason":"notFound","message":"Not Found"}]}}
```

what is wrong?

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=136

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently an issue with the JavaScript client Google is working on it.

[URGENT - Google Drive SDK JavaScript 404 Error on any method](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=136)